# Service Fabric fails to find resource file

Tags: .net-core, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I am having a problem deploying a microservice application to a remote Service Fabric cluster in Azure.

The application consists of 5 services, 4 of which manage to start and their state is displayed as `Ready`. However one fails with following error (state varies between `InBuild` and `Error` on all nodes):

```
'System.RA' reported Warning for property 'ReplicaOpenStatus'.
Replica had multiple failures during open on _nt1bm_5. API call: 
IStatelessServiceInstance.Open(); Error = 
System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException (-2146233038)
Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the 
neutral culture.  Make sure 
"Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.AspNetCore.SR.resources" was 
correctly embedded or linked into assembly 
"Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNetCore" at compile time, or that all the 
satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String fileName)
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreCommunicationListener.GetEndpointResourceDescription(String endpointName)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.AspNetCore.KestrelCommunicationListener.GetListenerUrl()
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreCommunicationListener.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.StatelessServiceInstanceAdapter.OpenCommunicationListenersAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.StatelessServiceInstanceAdapter.System.Fabric.IStatelessServiceInstance.OpenAsync(IStatelessServicePartition partition, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
For more information see: https://aka.ms/sfhealth
```

A few notes:

- All the services use almost exactly the same host initialization (ports vary)
- The application is configured to use HTTPS only
- The application in written using .NET Core 2.2
- The current Service Fabric version is 6.4.637.9590
- The host's operating system is Windows Server (probably 2012)
- On the local cluster, it works just fine
- Using .NET Core self-hosting, everything works

**What might be the cause of it?**

**How to debug such errors?**

**Is the source code of Service Fabric available somewhere to see code that fails?**

If you need any additional information just ask :)

Comment: The SF source is available at github, but it's C++, and cross-platform, and incredibly hard to slow through. I doubt that will lead you anywhere. Try this maybe? https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/331

Comment: Try updating the packages to the version `3.3.638`, there were some [issues](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24021) with packages from the most recent release.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the reason for this error!

Namely this error:

```
Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the 
neutral culture.
```

In the solution we had peculiar project structure:

- src:

  - self-hosted project (.NET Core app, all the controllers were here, as was `Startup` etc.)
  - Service Fabric Host (it used controllers and startup from self-hosted project, had its separate `Program.cs` and web host builder - suitable for Service Fabric)

Both the projects had different `appsettings.json` - but the names were the same (**!!!**)

When building and packing locally with Visual Studio everything was fine, but when building on Azure DevOps (regardless of used build type: `dotnet build`, `Visual Studio build`) strange error would occur.

In the package created for deployment (build .sfproj with `-t:Package`) even though we were referencing ServicFabric project `appsettings.json` were sometimes taken from self-host project. (which was different than `appsettings.json` from ServiceFabric project) The error came from trying to read non-existant entry in `appsettings.json`

**TLDR;**

The error came from trying to read non-existant entry in `appsettings.json`

Our current solution is to use different names for `appsettings.json` from different projects. If we find any better solution I will update the answer. Also any help on this matter would be appreciated.